# Using history command in Bash alias

Tags: bash

So I'm quite unfamiliar with Bash and am learning as I go along through trial and error. I'm wondering why the following doesn't work:

I define the function `repeat` in my bashrc file.

```
repeat () {
         history > /dev/null
         !-2
}
```

And then call it in the same file as follows:

```
alias .="repeat"
```

Yes, I know I'm hijacking the dot operator but I have my own alias for it (specifically for sourcing ~/.bashrc). The idea is to be able to write `.` and have it repeat the last command. This works if I type the commands manually in an interactive shell but doesn't work like this inside of an alias. Never mind that it's not repeatable more than once, I just want to get it working before I address that issue. When I type `.` I get the following output:

`bash: !-2: command not found`

I considered that `history` is not reading from my history file when called non-interactively and contains no commands in its history, but no, this outputs my history:

```
repeat () {
        history
        !-2
}
```

However, I get the same result. The `!` command doesn't seem to work.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: I have it working the way I want it now (please tell me if there is a more elegant solution) but I want to get rid of the command to be executed, i.e. I just want the output from the command itself. I thought I would try something like this:

```
 19 repeat () {
 20         for ((i = 0; i<${1}; i++ ))
 21         do
 22                 $(fc -s) | tail -n +2
 23         done
 24 }
 25
 26 alias .="repeat 1"
 27 alias 1.="repeat 1"
 28 alias 2.="repeat 2"
 29 alias 3.="repeat 3"
 30 alias 4.="repeat 4"
 31 alias 5.="repeat 5"
 32 alias 6.="repeat 6"
 33 alias 7.="repeat 7"
 34 alias 8.="repeat 8"
 35 alias 9.="repeat 9"
 36 alias 10.="repeat 10"
```

But it unfortunately doesn't work, it gives me the wrong output and then when I try again it enters an infinite loop. How do I achieve this?

Comment: commands executed in a function would not show up in command history.

Comment: I fail to understand the point of this alias. For the last command, you have the up arrow, with the benefit that you can check it before running. For a few commands before the last one, just tap the up arrow until you see the right command. That seems much easier and safer than remembering that the command you want would now have the number 5. And for older commands, you have Ctrl-R to search backwards through the history. And lastly, this will work on any other Linux or Mac machine with Bash, without any special configuration.

Comment: @mivk My up-arrow key is a double function key, which means it sends a different keycode depending on whether it's tapped or held down. So it feels slower than it would otherwise be and this is definitely quicker than what you suggested, which is what I have been doing for the longest time. However. I think you may have misunderstood these aliases a little, they do not refer to specific commands in the history but rather give a count to the repeat, just like in vim where you can type ``5.`` to repeat the last command five times. I would only use it to repeat a command I just typed in.

Comment: @Bridge Ah, sorry. I misunderstood what you wanted. And of course had no idea that you have strange arrow keys; I hope I never have to deal with such a keyboard...:-) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `fc` command which "*is used to list or edit and re-execute commands from the history list* ". Bash [manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) gives an example for this.

> A useful alias to use with this is `r="fc -s"`, so that typing `r cc` runs the last command beginning with `cc` and typing `r` re-executes the last command.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for.